# How to get the file format from a link with powershell

Tags: powershell, download

This is my project

```
cls


$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( $url -eq "")
{
    exit
}


[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.Forms")


function save-file([string]$initialDirectory)
{
    $savefile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog

    $savefile.InitialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $savefile.Filter="All files(*.*)|*.*"

    $savefile.ShowDialog() | out-null

    return $savefile.FileName

}


$file=save-file ""

if ( $file -eq "")
{
    exit
}
else
{
    echo "User Selected $file"
}



Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url" -OutFile "$file"
```

I will summarize the idea of the project

A program that downloads files from the browser using powershell.

I want the file to be saved automatically in the link format

**Is there a way to get the file format from a link using powershell or cmd?**

***I found the answer to my question (I will put the project so that anyone can benefit from it)***

```
cls


$url = Read-Host 'URL'
if ( $url -eq "")
{
    exit
}

$dot = $url.Split(".")[-1]

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.Forms")


function save-file([string]$initialDirectory)
{
    $savefile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog

    $savefile.InitialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $savefile.Filter="$dot file(*.$dot)|*.$dot"

    $savefile.ShowDialog() | out-null

    return $savefile.FileName

}


$file=save-file ""

if ( $file -eq "")
{
    exit
}
else
{
    echo "User Selected $file"
}



Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url" -OutFile "$file"
```

Comment: What did you mean by "Link format" ? can you give an example for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean how to extract the file name from a direct link like this one :

```
$URL = "https://cdn2.unrealengine.com/Fortnite%2FBoogieDown_GIF-1f2be97208316867da7d3cf5217c2486da3c2fe6.gif"
$FileName = $URL.Split("/")[-1]
$FileName
```

---

And if you want avoid to use BrowseForFolder and save automatically in a folder that will be created by the script for the first time of execution, try like his way :

```
$DownloadFolder = $Env:AppData + "\DownloadFolder\"
# Create a Download Folder if not exist yet to store files that will be downloaded in the future
If ((Test-Path -Path $DownloadFolder) -eq 0) { New-Item -Path $DownloadFolder -ItemType Directory | Out-Null }
$url = Read-Host 'URL'
$FileName = $url.Split("/")[-1]
if ( $url -eq ""){exit}
$FilePath = $DownloadFolder+$FileName
Write-Host "The file will be saved in this path ""$FilePath""" -Fore Green 
If ($FileName -eq ""){Exit} Else {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$url" -OutFile "$FilePath"}
```

Comment: Nice, but note that a simpler way to create a directory on demand is to use the `-Force` switch: `$null = New-Item -Type Directory -Force $DownloadFolder`. Quibble: If the URL at hand (better not to call it a _link_, which is a distinct construct of which a URL is a _part_) also includes a query string (e.g. `?foo=bar`), your approach won't work.

Answer (score 3):

To complement [Hackoo's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69870799/45375) with a slightly *more robust* version, which parses the URL (URI) via [`System.Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Uri):

```
PS> ([uri] 'https://example.org/downloads/foo.exe?other=stuff').Segments[-1]
foo.exe
```

The advantage of this approach is that any *query-string* suffix in the URL is *ignored*, which a strictly *string*-based parsing approach based on [`.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Split) would not.

Append `.Split('.')[-1]` to get just the filename *extension* (`exe`, in the example above), as also shown in your updated question, or enclose in [`[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.IO.Path.GetExtension) (which would yield `.exe`); in *PowerShell (Core) 7+* you could also use [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path) `-Extension` (also yields `.exe`).